# Splitting URL into host and path

Tags: java

I have a program that has a button which prints out the html text of a web address.I have got a variable that will have an address in the text box already, the issue is if I change the text in the text box to another address it will still print out the same html address. I've worded this issue badly but hopefully it's understandable. I want to be able to enter an URL and get that address html instead of going into the code eveytime and change the variable manually.

```
/* Create a HttpInteract object. */
    public HttpInteract(String url) {

        /* Split the "URL" into "host name" and "path name", and
        * set host and path class variables. 
        * if URL is only a host name, use "/" as path 
        */  
        System.out.println("URL splits into host name and path name.");
        host = "cgi.csc.liv.ac.uk";
        System.out.println("Host is:" +host);
        path = "/~gairing/test.txt";
        System.out.println("Path is:" +path);        

        //Request message. Connection closes after response because http 1.0
        //is non persistent
        requestMessage= "GET "+path+ " HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                        +"Host: " +host+  "\r\n"
                        +"\r\n" ;

        return;
    }
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html

Comment: The best thing is you use the class (see above) because it takes care of parsing. URL parsing looks easy but really is more complex than expected (think "Multilingual Web Addresses").

Answer (score 3):

Simple example using URL:

```
    // Note that you need protocol for valid URL
    URL url = new URL("http://cgi.csc.liv.ac.uk/~gairing/test.txt");

    System.out.println("Host:" + url.getHost());
    System.out.println("Path:" + url.getPath());
```

Comment: But I want to be able to have it so I can put any address, this just gets the same address each time doesn't it?

Comment: This is just an example. Put any URL you want. Just make sure that you have protocol in it.